# AsyncImage inside ForEach Loop

Tags: swift, asynchronous, foreach, swiftui, swiftui-asyncimage

I'm using stock AsyncImage to load an image from Firebase Storage to my app. I'm using two exactly same fragments of code to load the same image however the app compiles only when there is only the first fragment, the second one causes crash. The only difference between them is that I want to use the second one to display several same images in ForEach Loop.

**The first fragment:**

```
HStack {
    if let profilePicturePhotoURL = profileViewModel.profilePicturePhotoURL {
        AsyncImage(url: profilePicturePhotoURL) { phase in
            if let image = phase.image {
                image
                    .resizable()
            } else {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "blank-profile-hi")!)
            }
        }
    } else {
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "blank-profile-hi")!)
    }
    
    Text("What do you want to share?")
        .frame(width: screenWidth * 0.6, height: screenHeight * 0.1)
}
.padding(.leading, screenWidth * 0.05)
```

**The second fragment:**

```
if homeViewModel.posts != nil {
    ForEach(homeViewModel.posts!) { post in
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: .systemGray6))
                .frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight * 0.02)
            
            HStack {
                if let profilePicturePhotoURL = profileViewModel.profilePicturePhotoURL {
                    AsyncImage(url: profilePicturePhotoURL) { phase in
                        if let image = phase.image {
                            image
                                .resizable()
                        } else {
                            Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "blank-profile-hi")!)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "blank-profile-hi")!)
                }
```

Leaving only

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "blank-profile-hi")!)
```

as the image of the second fragment makes images display properly.

Comment: What does the crash message say?

Comment: `AsyncImage` works well for me in my ForEach loop tests. 
Given that you want the same image several times, it would be better 
(and a lot more efficient) to download the image once, in `.onAppear` 
for example, and use that same image in the loop.